# Confusion over MvxFragmentActivity and MvxFragment

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm currently working on an app for Android and Windows, and I came across a blocker. I was about to use Navigation Tabs to my activity, then I noticed that this feature uses "newer" fragments, and **MvxFragment** is based on an older fragment.

This is the code I use to load my fragments:

```
protected void AttachViewModels<TFragment>(BaseViewModel pageViewModel, BaseViewModel contentViewModel, int contentResourceID)
               where TFragment : MvxFragment
{
    // Set the ViewModel for the fragment
    var fragment = (TFragment)SupportFragmentManager.FindFragmentById (contentResourceID);
    fragment.ViewModel = contentViewModel;
}
```

My questions is: Do I REALLY need to use **MvxFragmentActivity** and **MvxFragment**? Can I simply replace all my **MvxFragmentActivity** and **MvxFragment** with **FragmentActivity** and **Fragment**?

My project targets a minimum of Android 4.4, nothing lower.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MvvmCross there are 2 types of fragments: "Support fragging" and "Full fragging". It depends on which of those packages you have installed if you are using the correct Fragment base class.

In your code i see you use `SupportFragmentManager` so i guess you want to use the "Support fragments". If you use MvvmCross in your app, it is not adviced to use `Fragment` instead of `MvxFragment`

We have a sample here that shows how you could use fragments in MvvmCross: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples

Comment: What benefit do I get from using MvxFragment over Fragment? I can't use these for Navigation Tabs in the action bar.

Comment: By using MvvmCross and MvxFragment you can use ViewModels for the fragment. If you want to use tabs in the action bar, look at this sample: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-AndroidSupport/tree/master/Samples/Example.Droid

Comment: The mvvmcross links are dead.